# asp.net mvc diff between DeleteAllOnSubmit and deleteonSubmit

Tags: .net, database, linq-to-sql, delete-row

What is the real difference b/w DeleteAllOnSubmit and deleteonSubmit and which one is more appropiate to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as `DeleteOnSubmit` nor `DeleteAllOnSubmit` in ASP.NET MVC, so I'll assume that you mean the methods in LINQ to SQL tables. (Correct me if not.)

Basically, you use `DeleteOnSubmit` to delete a single row from a table, by specifying a single entity which maps to the row you want to delete.

`DeleteAllOnSubmit` is there for you if you want to delete multiple rows from a table, by specifying multiple entities, more correctly an `IEnumerable<>` of those, which means that you can specify them in more or less any collection. (`List<T>`, `Collection<T>`, and many more.)